# Evaluate at runtime if a series of boolean conditions is valid or not

Tags: java

I have a list of boolean conditions like `== 4`, `< 5`, `> 1` and so on. Now what I would like to know if a series of and constraints is possible. Lets say `< 5 > 1` is possible while `< 5 > 9` is not. I have thought of feeding the strings into nashorn but this brings me nowhere. How can I achieve this? Or is there any library out there doing the job?

EDIT: I have exactly 3 operators ==, <= and >= and doubles not integers (yes in real life the lesser or higher means lesser/higher equals - but that should not make a difference). Maybe I could scale up doubles i.e. 1022.30 -> 10223

Comment: Are your constraints string arguments? "==4", "<5", etc

Comment: @JamesWierzba in fact they are instances of `Pair<enum, Double>` where enum can be equals, less, greater, .. you got it.

Comment: Is there any restriction on what those conditions look like? From your examples, I assume they might only operate in the `int` domain, and only `==`, `<` and `>` operators; is that correct?

Comment: If you can use Guava's Range, you can create a `Range<Double>` for each condition (e.g. `Range.singleton(4)`, `Range.upTo(5)` etc), and just keep taking the intersection of the ranges until you end up with an empty range (or not).

Comment: Alternatively, if they are all integer bounds, you can do it without Range quite easily: `== 4` is the range `[4, 4]`; `< 5` is the range `[Integer.MIN_VALUE, 4]` etc. Just take the max of the lower bounds, min of the upper bounds, and see if `min <= max`.

Comment: Do you want to check all the constraints in the list on some variable `X`?

Comment: Your question is intriguing, could you post the actual code, and maybe a sample dataset or two?

Comment: @AndyTurner actually I like that idea, I am trying this out at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your bounds are integers, you can convert each of your conditions into a closed range. For example:

- `= x` is `[x, x]`
- `< x` is `[Integer.MIN_VALUE, x - 1]`
- `> x` is `[x + 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE]`

etc.

You can build one of these ranges for each of your input conditions, and then take the intersection of the ranges by calculating the maximum of the lower bounds, and the minimum of the lower bounds.

If the max of the lower bounds `<=` the min of the upper bounds, the condition can be satisfied.

Example for integers:

```
boolean canBeSatisfied(Iterable<Pair<enum, Integer>> conditions) {
  int maxLower = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int minUpper = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (Pair<enum, Integer> condition : conditions) {
    maxLower = Math.max(maxLower, getLowerBound(condition));
    minUpper = Math.min(minUpper, getUpperBound(condition));
  }
  return maxLower <= minUpper;
}
```

and then define `getLowerBound` and `getUpperBound` something like:

```
int getLowerBound(Pair<enum, Integer> condition) {
  switch (condition.first) {
  case EQUALS:
  case GE:
    return condition.second;
  case GT:
    return condition.second + 1;
  case LT: case LE:
    return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  }
}

int getUpperBound(Pair<enum, Integer> condition) {
  switch (condition.first) {
  case EQUALS:
  case GE: case GT:
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  case LT:
    return condition.second - 1;
  case LE:
    return condition.second;
  }
}
```

You can extend the same idea to double bounds, but you need to be a little bit more careful to handle the difference between closed and open bounds.

If you can use Guava, you can do all of this directly with the `Range` class, using the factory methods to construct appropriate instances of the ranges, and then just taking the intersection of all range instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `interface` for the operators instead of an `enum`. This will make you able subclass to this interface for all operators:

```
// File: Main.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Pair<L,R> {
    L left;
    R right;

    public Pair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

interface Operator {

    boolean calculate(double lhs, double rhs);
}

public class Main {

    private static Operator equals = new Operator() {

        @Override
        public boolean calculate(double lhs, double rhs) {
            return lhs == rhs;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "==";
        }
    };



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double x = 3.14;

        List<Pair<Operator, Double>> constraints = new ArrayList<>();
        constraints.add(new Pair(equals, 5.0));
        constraints.add(new Pair(equals, 3.14));

        for (Pair<Operator, Double> constraint : constraints) {

            Operator operator = constraint.left;
            double value = constraint.right;

            boolean result = operator.calculate(x, value);

            System.out.println(x + operator.toString() + value + "=" + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is reinventing the wheel to some extent. You can just use a [BiPredicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) as the interface.

Comment: @James_D I do not agree, it is much more educative to make this yourself. Furthermore, this is much more extensible than using a predicate. Besides `BiPredicate` is Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your setup, but assuming there are only three operators (`>`, `<`, and `==`), there are only three major cases to handle:

```
  | > | < | ==
--+---+---+---
> |   | B | A 
--+---+---+---
< | B |   | C 
--+---+---+---
==| A | C |
```

(sorry for the ugly table)

First, you need to detect the case, then define methods for each one, e.g.

```
possibleA(int biggerThan, int equalTo) {
    return equalTo > biggerThan;
}
```

and analogous for case B and C.